# Line of text cut horizontally into two when printing large text

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a div occasionally containing very long text - more than one page in one div. This needs to be printed and when printing some lines of are split horizontally when the page brakes. Tried everything I could find on Stack Overflow and other sources.

I had tried all combinations of page-break

Tried setting body margin to 0%

Tried pagination

Tried display block/inline

[image]

Comment: can you not copy-paste the text into notepad++ or some other text editor and print from there?

Comment: Sorry, you probably already tried, but just in case, did you try `line-height: normal`?

Comment: @DrCord unfortunately, the end user needs to print it out, so using copy and paste will not work.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks, yes I tried that as well with no change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you put:

```
{ overflow: auto !important; }
```

On the content, when in print mode.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Miaan. This did not work either. I am getting fed up with this one and may just re-design the whole page...