# Chrome cuts text horizontally when printing

Tags: css, sharepoint, printing

I'm attempting to make a button that'll open the print dialog on a SharePoint page, and got it pretty much working, except in chrome where for some reason chrome cuts text horizontally at page breaks, when I test in edge dev it works as intetned.

I fount this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282994/line-of-text-cut-horizontally-into-two-when-printing-large-text/), and tried, but to no avail

My custom CSS

```
@media print {

    [class^='ms-CommandBar'],
    [role='banner'],
    #O365_NavHeader,
    #SuiteNavPlaceHolder,
    [class^='button'],
    #HideMeToo {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .SPCanvas {
        background: #FFF !important;
    }

    [class^="backgroundImage"] {
        background: #FFF !important;
    }
}
```

So I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here are links to the images.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRXWT.png)

[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hLeH.png)